# for loop, misunderstanding

Tags: java, for-loop, computer-science

just to note, i am new CS student, so i barely understand whats going on

The question at hand is to find totA and totB, now i know the answer is 10 and 5. But i dont understand how it gets this answer.
When i try to do this my self the answer i get is totA = 12, and totB = 6

I got totA by adding 6 first, then adding the 4 after the second loop and finally get 12 as the answer.
for totB, i assume do to there being two ++, with i++ and totB++, this should result to 6

If someone could help correct my misunderstanding that will be very helpful
Thank you

public class MyClass {
public static void main(String args[]) {

```
    int valone = 6;
    int valtwo = 2;
   
    int totA = 0;
    int totB = 0;
    
    for(int i=valone; i>valtwo i=i-2) {
        totA = totA + i;
    }
   
    for(int i=valtwo; i<=valone; i++) {
        totB++;
    }
    
  System.out.println(valone);
  System.out.println(valtwo);
  System.out.println(totA);
  System.out.println(totB);
 
}
```

}

Comment: I suspect the point you're missing is what happens with the condition that allows the loop to continue. This check is made at the *start* of each loop, not at the end. For example, the first loop will execute as long as `i > valueTwo` is true. A soon as it is not true, the loop will not repeat. Given that, what values of `i` will you have each time through the loop? It starts at 6, which is `> value Two` then 4 which is `> valueTwo` but then as soon as it becomes 2, the loop stops. It doesn't execute with the value w because the check occurs at the beginning of the loop. Whereas the

Comment: If you read a language manual carefully about the `for` loop, you'll understand. `for (exp1 ; exp2 ; exp3)` will first execute `exp1`. Then before each loop iteration it executes `exp2` and will stop looping of that expression is false. If it does run the loop, then at the end of each loop iteration, it executes `exp3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the state at the end of each iteration for both loops.

Loop 1

```
iteration | totA | i
#1          6    | 4
#2          10   | 2
```

The value of `i` (`2`) is equal to `valueTwo` (`2`) after the second iteration, which fails to satisfy that `i > valueTwo`,  so the loop terminates when `totA` is `10`.

Loop 2

```
iteration | totB | i
#1          1      3
#2          2      4
#3          3      5
#4          4      6
#5          5      7
```

The value of `i` (`7`) is greater than `valueOne` (`6`), which fails to satisfy that `i <= valueOne` so the loop terminates when `totB` is `5`.